# android app hangs starting a service

Tags: android, android-intentservice

I'm try to create a simple service.

this is the service source

```
public class UploadService extends IntentService {

    public UploadService(String name) {
        super(name);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
        Toast.makeText(this, "service starting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(this, "handling intent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

this is the definition of the service in the manifest

```
<service 
    android:enabled="true" 
    android:name="com.sopla.Services.UploadService">
</service>
```

this is the code I use to start the service in the onCreate method of the main Activity called at the startup of the program

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this,
            com.sopla.Services.UploadService.class);
    startService(intent);
```

I can debug all the onCreate method, but after this the program hangs, and I cannot reach the breakpoint in the service source code.

I'm missing something?
thanks,
  Luca

Comment: **"android app hangs starting a service"** : Post your logcat output. Just saying it "hangs" doesn't help anyone help you.

Answer (score 0):

try this for your onStartCommand:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    TODO do something useful
    return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks to every one, but checking better the logcat I found the problem.
For some strange reason, asking the Ide to add the missing members of IntentService add a costructor with a string, but at runtime a constructor without is reguired.
Removing the string parameter from the costructor solved the problem.